# get value from another url in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The ASP.NET web app that I am writing has the following: 
1. an input TextBox that accepts stock code 
2. a Label in an AJAX UpdatePanel that should display the stock value

I want to get the value from the stock value field on the yahoo page 
'("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert&fr=&type=2button&s="+"myStockCode")' and display it in my Label field. 
Unable to find anywhere on the net.  Would someone know how to access fields on an external document? 
For example, the stock value field on the yahoo finance page is in the following tag -
`<span id="yfs_l84_goog">508.08</span>`
(for google, for example - they're all similar except for the code part whose value I have anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a value from external resources by several ways.

First is using Javascript and XMLHttpRequest property. I suggest you to look at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Second is, most probably the web site gives values as RSS format or something like that. You can access the file and parse desired value.